# Como funciona os eventos no jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Mostrarei exemplos apenas do evento click para ficar mais simples de explicar, porem esta dúvida e referente a qualquer evento jquery.

Quando eu comecei a utilizar o jquery eu só utilizava o evento click da seguinte forma:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  alert('ok');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Confirmar</button>
```

Que por sinal funcionava muito bem, mas depois eu comecei a fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
$("#area").html($("<button/>").text('Outro botão'));

//Primeira forma
$("button").click(function(){
  alert('ok 1');
});

//Segunda forma
$("button").on('click', function(){
  alert('ok 2');
});

//Terceira forma
$('#area').on('click', 'button', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('ok 3');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Confirmar</button>
<div id="area"></div>
```

Coloquei mais dois exemplos, a "segunda forma" eu comecei a utilizar porque eu reparei que as vezes quando eu criava um elemento dinamicamente com o jquery a "primeira forma" de utilizar o evento click não funcionava, utilizei esta forma por um bom tempo, até que um dia ela também não funcionou então descobrir a "terceira forma" e assim eu consigo colocar o evento click em qualquer elemento sem problemas.

Mas a minha "técnica" é a seguinte, tento a primeira, não funciona vou para segunda e por sua vez não funcionou passo para a terceira.

O que eu quero saber é o porque, isso é uma característica do jquery, é por causa do javascript, porque as vezes funciona e porque as vezes não funciona, é isso que eu queria saber, eu utilizo os eventos mas eu não sei o porque deste comportamento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **primeira** é um atalho para `$("button").on('click', function(){`

```
$("button").click(function(){
  alert('ok 1');
});
```

Pode conferir em no próprio source do repositório oficial [`alias.js#L10`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/event/alias.js#L10), isto:

```
jQuery.each( ( "blur focus focusin focusout resize scroll click dblclick " +
    "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
    "change select submit keydown keypress keyup contextmenu" ).split( " " ),
    function( i, name ) {

    // Handle event binding
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( data, fn ) {
        return arguments.length > 0 ?
            this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
            this.trigger( name );
    };
} );
```

Veja que tem o `this.on( name, null, data, fn )`, o `.trigger` só é executado se não passar o `function`, fizer isto por exemplo `$("...").click();`, que é usado para disparar o evento.

---

A **segunda** é a "padrão", e com ela você também poder criar eventos próprios fazendo uso do [`.trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$("button").on('click', function(){
  alert('ok 2');
});
```

---

A **terceira** forma na verdade se trata de delegação de evento, o `click` ocorre no `#area`, mas o evento é só disparado se o elemento que disparou o `click` em `#area` "casar" com a query do segundo parametro, ou seja `button`

```
$('#area').on('click', 'button', function () {
    alert('ok 3');
});
```

A vantagem do terceiro sobre os demais é que você não precisaria usar coisas como `$.ready` ou `$(window).load` para definir o evento click no botão, ele próprio já reconhece se existe o botão em `#area`, já que a checagem da delegação só ocorre no momento do click

---

> 1. a "primeira forma" de utilizar o evento click não funcionava
> 2. O que eu quero saber é o porque, isso é uma característica do jquery, é por causa do javascript, porque as vezes funciona e porque as vezes não funciona, é isso que eu queria saber, eu utilizo os eventos mas eu não sei o porque deste comportamento.

Isto provavelmente foi alguma confusão sua, é **improvável** que `.on('click')` funcionasse e `.click` não, já que é apenas um atalho, as unicas possibilidades possiveis, creio eu, de terem causado a falha seriam:

- Um bug na versão especifica do jQuery que você esta usando
- Algum add-on para jQuery que afetou seus scripts
- Foi apenas alguma confusão sua, talvez outros eventos com `stopPropagation` ou algo semelhante que tenha impedido e você os removeu quando trocou para `.on` sem perceber.

---

> Mas a minha "técnica" é a seguinte, tento a primeira, não funciona vou para segunda e por sua vez não funcionou passo para a terceira.

Eu pessoalmente optaria sempre pela terceira, é simples, não precisa checar se o DOM existe, se criar elemento novo vai funcionar, se remover não precisará fazer muita coisa, se necessita que qualquer elemento com uma classe ou atributo especifico na página tenha o evento basta usar `document`, exemplo:

```
$(document).on('click', '#area button', function () {
    alert('ok 3');
});
```

Ou assim (nesse caso elementos com classes foo e bar irão disparar o evento):

```
$(document).on('click', '.foo, .bar', function () {
    alert('ok 3');
});
```